# Translate Braille into matlab (after filtering)

Tags: matlab

[image: braille]

As shown in the picture above, the Braille X,Y locations are complete. However, I don't know how to divide the zones in 3x2 rows to match the average size of the objects. Please let me know.
If there are any other coding methods other than Matlab, please recommend them.

centroids =

1.0e+03 *

```
0.1515    0.1635
0.2419    0.0806
0.3619    0.2506
0.3624    0.0804
0.3640    0.1652
0.4492    0.2505
0.4503    0.1661
0.4518    0.0822
0.5705    0.1669
0.5748    0.0806
0.6598    0.2502
0.9878    0.0809
1.0748    0.0796
1.0768    0.1646
1.1979    0.1630
1.2830    0.2476
1.2855    0.0772
1.4911    0.1603
1.6120    0.0774
1.6141    0.1608
1.7034    0.2460
1.8217    0.0756
1.8272    0.2453
1.9147    0.1622
2.0306    0.1578
2.1241    0.2462
```

This is my coordinates. However, the coordinates are only about this picture, and the values of the coordinates change when you insert another picture.

````
```matlab code

I = imread('sample1.png');        % 이미지 불러오기
H = imgaussfilt(I, 2);           % 흐림 필터
T = rgb2gray(H);                 % 회색조 필터
Q = imadjust(T,[0.5 0.8],[]);    % 명암 조절
BW = imbinarize(Q);              % 흑백화 필터
bw2 = imcomplement(BW);          % 흑백 반전 필터
BW2 = bwareaopen(bw2, 800);      % 800픽셀 이하 객체 제거
s = regionprops(BW2,'centroid'); % 객체 중앙 좌표 찍기
centroids = cat(1,s.Centroid);
imshow(BW2)
hold on
plot(centroids(:,1),centroids(:,2),'ro')
hold off
```
````

Comment: My understanding is that the black and white picture is actually a picture. However I also see some red circles in it, so I suspect you have the coordinates of those points. Is this right?

Comment: yes, it is correct

Comment: Well, provide those coordinates.

Comment: I revised the text. Please check it.